# 32-bit runtime flag in SQL Agent - msdb location

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent

Does anyone know if the 32-bit runtime flag in the 'Configuration' >  'Advanced' tab within a job step has a location in `msdb` (or elsewhere)?  I'm looking to set the flag as part of an automated deployment.

[image]

Comment: `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps` contains the full definition of the command line used to run SSIS, which this interface will dutifully parse and reconstruct when you change something (although there are some bugs where it fails if the configuration becomes very complex). If you're automating this, it means you're looking at scripting an `sp_add_jobstep` or `sp_update_jobstep` call with the full command line. Adding or removing it on the fly is possible, but not a fun thing to do in T-SQL, given its weaknesses at string parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its located in `command` in `sysjobsteps` as an inline parameter. The following will return any 32bit jobs you have:

```
 USE msdb;
 GO

 SELECT *
 FROM dbo.sysjobsteps
 WHERE subsystem = 'SSIS'
   AND command LIKE '%/x86%';
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I just to add it as an argument to my command line when scripting the job.